# Как использовать 2 метода одновременно и возможно ли это?

Tags: python, методы

У меня есть такой код и мне нужно использовать два метода: *.title* и *.split* возможно ли записать две эти строки кода аккуратнее, в одну?

```
def abbrev_name(names):
    names = names.title()
    names = names.split()
    return f'{names[0][0]}.{names[1][0]}'
```

Comment: Одновременно нельзя, можно последовательно: `names = names.title().split()`. А вообще, лучше уточнить, какой конкретно результат вы хотите получить.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! В следующий раз я это учту.